# Place in new div when match space in string

Tags: php, html

I have this html

```
<span class="item-title">Title</span>  
<span class="item-cat">sub-text</span>
```

I have in database string like `Title sub-text`. How can I place `sub-text` in bottom `<span>` when str_replace match space? I've tried something like this

```
<span class="item-title">'.str_replace(' ',"<span class="item-cat">sub-text</span>",$row['category']).'</span>
```

But seems not right because I don't know how to divide the string and show only second part in second div. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `sub-text` have any spaces?

Comment: No, they will be always two words. 1 word for Title and one word for sub-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of sub-text won't have any spaces you can simply use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function create two strings. One for title and another one for sub-text.

Code would look seomthing like this,

```
<?php

$mainTitle="Title sub-text";
$parts=explode(" ",$mainTitle);

?>

<span class="item-title"><?php echo $parts[0]; ?></span>  
<span class="item-cat"><?php echo $parts[1]; ?></span>

<?php // Other code ?>
```

> **explode()** just split the string by space( in this case) which will create array of two elements, of which first one is `title` and second
>   one would be `sub-text`.

Answer (score 1):

To split this you can use this

```
<?php
    $str = 'Title sub-text';
    $myarray = str_word_count ($str,1);
   // echo  $myarray[0]; // Title
    //echo $myarray[1]; // sub-text
?>

<span class="item-title"><?php echo $myarray[0]; ?></span>  
<span class="item-cat"><?php echo $myarray[1]; ?></span>
```

For more info about `str_word_count` please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

**Note:** You can also use `explode`.